# js common function which calculates and assign to object values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, this

Example of what i'm trying to achieve

I want to make an object in react which will calculate one its key value from other keys using this function and the 'this' keyword so that I can use this function dynamically with many input fields object.

```js
func = function (c) {
    return this.a + this.b + c;
};

obj1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    value: func(5),
};

obj2 = [
    { a: 2, b: 3, value: func(6) },
    {
        a: 4,
        b: 5,
        value: func(7),
    },
];

// expected result
console.log(obj1.value); // 8
console.log(obj2[0].value); // 16
```

Comment: Relevant: [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest solution would to flip this around: Pass the object to the function, let it add the property and return the very same object:

```js
const func = function (obj, c) {
  obj.value = obj.a + obj.b + c;
  return obj;
};

const obj1 = func({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
}, 5);

const obj2 = [
    func({ a: 2, b: 3 }, 6),
    func({
        a: 4,
        b: 5,
    }, 7),
];

// expected result
console.log(obj1.value); // 8
console.log(obj2[0].value); // 16
```

(no idea how the second example would result in 16 though)

Answer (score -1):

At the moment `func` is called, `this` is set to `window` object, because the object you want to use it in, doesn't exist yet.

You can try returning a function from `func`

```js
const func = function(c) {
  return function() {
    return this.a + this.b + c
  }
}

const obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  value: func(5),
}

const obj2 = [{
    a: 2,
    b: 3,
    value: func(6)
  },
  {
    a: 4,
    b: 5,
    value: func(7)
  }
]

// expected result
console.log(obj1.value()) // 8
console.log(obj2[0].value()) // 11
```

Comment: this is not working in runtime i think.

Comment: @xxxhomie21 I don't understand your comment

Comment: value key must not be a function it must be a return value of the function. I'm passing it as a string prop to a text component. And I don't want to call it in the component as it is a common component.

Comment: Cannot be done without a class or a proxy

Comment: ok, thanks I wanted to know if it's possible or not.